# define recyclerview click NOT as a member of constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

from reading many website im aware that the optimal way handling onclick on recycerview was to set clicklistener not in OnBindViewHolder, its either in onCreateViewHolder(explained in [here](https://oozou.com/blog/a-better-way-to-handle-click-action-in-a-recyclerview-item-60)) or pass the clickListener in "bind" method(explained in [here](https://medium.com/android-gate/recyclerview-item-click-listener-the-right-way-daecc838fbb9)).

but one thing that really bother me, was how clickListener handled in activity / fragment

```
val adapter : MyAdapter(){
//click goes here
}
```

it may be not much but, honestly its not so so readable

i prefer to handle click listener not in constuctor, but with on separate method, meyabe like this

```
adapter.onItemClickListner = {
val adapter = MyAdapter()
//click more readable, yay!
}
```

but im not sure, if its will affect performance or not, or do i really need to stick with click on constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself have used this method before.. Instead of passing the listener in the constructor, I have set it explicitly from the method call as you described. When I used that approach I had to make sure in the adapter that i checked for initialization of the listener and its null safety. So, you'll have to make sure before calling that it's absolutely present and initialized before calling the listener methods in the adapter.

I gradually moved to constructor as I didn't want to have such conscious checks all over my adapter before any click. (When there were like multiple clickable views.)

Answer (score 0):

create a `interface` which has some `function` to handle your onClick.

Now you need to `implement` this `interface` in your `activity` class like this :-

`class MainActivity : InterfaceAdapterOnClick` (Here `InterfaceAdapterOnClick` is an interface which will have some functions to handle your `onClick`)

Let's suppose we have one `function` named `onClickItem` in our `interface`.

So now when you create your adapter like this `adapter = MyAdapter()` you can pass your interface with that. So it should look like :-

`var adapter = MyAdapter(this)` (`this` because you have already implemented `interface` in your `mainActivity` class) and your adapter should look like :-

```
class MyAdapter(onClickHandler: InterfaceAdapterOnClick) {}
```

So with this at the end you will have a seperate `interface` method in your `mainActivity` and your `mainAcitvity` should look like :-

```
class MainActivity : InterfaceAdapterOnClick {

    // This will be your seperate onClick handler for your recyclerView item

     override func onClickItem(// You can take some parameter as input here like `posistion` or `adapterItem` here ) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, If your adapter needs that `itemClickListener` to function properly then you should pass it through its constructor and passing it using a setter function is not good since you might forgot to pass it at some point you forget to pass the listener and waste your time to check why clicking on items does not work! (It happened to me :D). If you are concerned about readability then you can use an interface and pass the implementation to adapter or use some features of `Kotlin` like named parameter or pass the callable reference of a function to make it more readable. For example something like this

```
class MyAdapter(onItemClick: (MyData) -> Unit) {
    // ...
}
```

And initialize it like this

```
val adapter = MyAdapter(
    onItemClick = { data -> 
        // ...
    }
)
```

or pass the function like this

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreateView(/**/) { 
        // ...

        val adapter = MyAdapter(
            onItemClick = ::onItemClick
        )
        // or
        // val adapter = MyAdapter(::onItemClick)
    }

    private fun onItemClick(data: MyData) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass an interface between the activity and the adapter class but the best method is by passing a function to your adapter class, like this

```
     adapter = BasketRVA { basketEntity: BasketEntity, minus: Boolean -> changeQuantity(basketEntity, minus) }

       private fun changeQuantity(basketEntity: BasketEntity, minus: Boolean) {
///your code
}
```

and in the adapter type this

```
class BasketRVA(private val clickListener: (BasketEntity, Boolean)->Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<BasketRVA.BasketViewHolder>()
```

and in your viewHolder class and bind function

```
 inner class BasketViewHolder(binding: BasketItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun bind(basketEntity: BasketEntity?, clickListener: (BasketEntity, Boolean) -> Unit){
        binding.tvProductName.text = basketEntity?.productName
```

in your binding function create a click listener for your view and pass the function you want to proceed

```
binding.imMinus.setOnClickListener {
            val minus = true
            clickListener(basketEntity!!, minus)
        }
```

in your bind viewHolder

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BasketViewHolder, position: Int) {
    BasketViewHolder(binding).bind(basketList[position], clickListener)
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: basket list position is ${basketList[position]}")
}
```

Ask me if you still have any question